# Is 'could be possible' the same as 'is possible'?

Tags: meaning

If I have a bag of dice, and ask, "Is it possible to roll a 7?" what is the answer? I understand that, if I ask if I dump dice out of a bag, it's possible, but once I pick the bag, and don't know if there are 8 or 15, or 2 dice in it...is it possible, or just could be possible, since it could be impossible based on my information?

Comment: Surely if something could be possible, it is possible. Introducing more levels of probability doesn't affect the overall calculation's result of "It might happen".

Comment: The levels aren't the problem..once I choose a bag...we don't know how  many dice are in it..and it is set...if I have a bag with 8 dice..it's impossible...since it could be a bag with 8 dice...it could be possible, but we don't know how many dice..so it could be impossible...As long as we leave this as some random bag..it is possible, but once I choose a bag, it has to have between 2 and 7 dice, or it's impossible...no chance at all.

Comment: The fact that it is possible means that it is possible. It is not known to be completely impossible, so it is possible. Possible/impossible is a binary function. "Could be possible" simply means "possible".

Comment: @Andrew The term 'possible' is used with differing degrees of substantiation. Albert may not know that 'It is always possible to find a subset of three adjacent natural numbers that add up to a multiple of 3'. He ought to say 'It could be [that what you ask is] possible'.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but my thought process says *could be possible = possible(possible(x))* which is distinct from *possible(x)*

Comment: @AlexW is right. What Andrew could have and perhaps should have said is "*Surely if something is possible, it could be possible.*" *possible(x)* implies *possible(possible(x))*, but not the converse. That said, I'm not sure that any of this is germane to what the OP is really trying to ask.

Comment: Someone is justified in saying 'E may be possible' when E is actually impossible, but they're ignorant of the fact.

Comment: This is actually the discussion I am looking for. In the example, we know the specific bag. Now, I know the number of dice is 9. You don't know this. I ask, is it possible that I roll a 7. Is possible and impossible different for us? Is it possible to you, but impossible to me..or is it impossible for both of us, only you don't know. This has sparked a 5 day argument and I am really hoping for a consensus.

Comment: Impossibility is independent from any observer. It is absolute. If there are 9 dice, it is impossible that either of you will roll a 7. It is impossible for both of you, you are merely aware of the impossibility while someone who does not know there are 9 dice might *think* it is possible. Thinking something is possible and reality are completely different.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "might or might not be possible [depending on whether.....]

Comment: Harriet Baber, thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. I can go on with my life now...thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the bag contains a die with 7 pips on each face.  Then, you may roll a 7.

Lewis Carroll poses a problem in **Pillow Problems** that would amuse you.  There are 3 balls in a bag, each ball being either white or black.  Problem: ascertain the colors of the 3 balls without taking them out of the bag.  Surprisingly, there is a solution, based on probability theory, which Carroll gives.

While I have some difficulty finding any grammatical principle that bears on your question, there is an issue in modal logic whether it is different to say something is possibly possible than it is to say it is possible.

Comment: The solution Carroll gives is unsurprisingly fallacious [ [Esperson_Seneta](http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/eseneta/l.carroll.1984.pdf)].

Comment: Thanks for the reference, @Edwin. Evidently my memory failed me -- there were 2 balls in the sack originally, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference.  If it's "possible" to build a house out of sugar cubes that means that one could do it if they had the will and resources. (Note that this is using "possible" in a different sense from the probability sense.)  If it "could be possible" that simply means that there's no known "roadblock" to accomplishing the task -- whether it can really be done remains to be proven.  (Eg, it could work out that the weight of so many sugar cubes would cause the ones on the bottom to fracture, but the calculations to determine that have not been done.)

In the rigorous probability sense, if something is "possible" that means there's a non-zero probability that it will occur.  If it "could be possible", that means that the probability is unknown, but there's no known reason for the probability to be zero.

And in informal use the meaning roughly parallels the sugar cube example -- if I say it's "possible" that I can come to your party tomorrow then (if I'm being honest) that means that if the day works out tomorrow I can come, whereas if it "could be possible" then I'm saying that I know there are potential conflicts (eg, girlfriend may have other plans) but I haven't worked them out yet.  Or something roughly along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

‘Possible’ is ambiguous. It can be understood in an epistemic possibility or in an alethic sense. Suppose there are in fact 8 dice in the bag—as you only discover later when you dump the out. Even before you made that discovery, it was not possible in the alethic sense to roll 7 with those dice. But it was possible in the epistemic sense, that it it was *for all you **knew*** possible.

The issue isn’t probability but ambiguity between alethic or straight-up possibility and epistemic or for-all-you-know possibility. Consider a cleaner example: you’re taking a multiple choice math test (as in SAT). Before doing the calculation you know the answer has to be positive, so you rule out options D and E which are negative and say to yourself, ‘It *could* be A, B or C’—those answers are possible in the epistemic sense. They’re plausible answers. But one of those answers, the correct answer, has a probability of 1 while the other two have probabilities of zero.